# Add a new set of properties to all fields in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I need to add a new property to all the fields in YAML file.

Suppose, I have the following YAML file.

```
Global:
  config:
    password: pwd
    user: temp_user
  config2:
    password: pwd
    user2: temp_user2
App1:
  name: temp_name
  value: value1
App2:
  name: temp_name_1
```

This is our config yaml file, now what we want is as below.

```
Global:
  _metadata_:
    description: Global
    hidden: true
    type: String
  config:
    _metadata_:
      description: config
      hidden: true
      type: String
    password:
      _metadata_:
        description: password
        hidden: true
        type: String
    user:
      _metadata_:
        description: user
        hidden: true
        type: String
  config2:
    _metadata_:
      description: config2
      hidden: true
      type: String
    password:
      _metadata_:
        description: password
        hidden: true
        type: String
    user2:
      _metadata_:
        description: user2
        hidden: true
        type: String
App1:
  _metadata_:
    description: App1
    hidden: true
    type: String
  name:
    _metadata_:
      description: name
      hidden: true
      type: String
  value:
    _metadata_:
      description: value
      hidden: true
      type: String
App2:
  _metadata_:
    description: App2
    hidden: true
    type: String
  name:
    _metadata_:
      description: name
      hidden: true
      type: String
```

I am trying to achieve this using python ruamel.yaml library but not able to achieve it. As you see in the above example, I need to clear the values and add the same set of new properties.

What would be a simpler and easier way to achieve this using 'ruamel' or any other library? I would appreciate any help.

Note: I have a huge file with many comments inside it. To preserve the comments I am using ruamel.

Comment: The simplest way is to write a program ;-). Even if yours failed, you should include a minimal (failing) version in your question, so we comment upon that in an answer. . Maybe the wrong terminology leads you astray? There are no fields and properties in YAML. Your YAML has mappings with keys and values. Some of your values are mappings themselves, the others, and the keys, are all scalars. In Python this translates to dicts (in ruamel.yaml subclasses of dicts), which also have keys and values.

Comment: `ruamel.yaml` should be able to do what you want, although if there are in reality comments in the section of the file shown, they might not end up where you expect them as you change single line values to multi-line values.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where the problem lies as you did not present a failing program. A
simple depth-first recursive function can replace the values with the dict like
object, on which you can insert the `_metadata` key. You only have to keep
notify the (recursive) caller that the value is a scalar, in which case it needs
replacing with ruamel.yaml's dict like object that allows insertion:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

in_file = Path('in.yaml')

def rewrite_keys(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        exp_list = []
        for k in d:
            if rewrite_keys(d[k]):
                d[k] = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
            exp_list.append(k)
        for x in exp_list:
            md = dict(description=x, hidden=True, type="String")
            d[x].insert(0, '_metadata', md)
        return False
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for item in d:
             rewrite_keys(d[item])
    else:
        return True

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(in_file)
rewrite_keys(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
Global:
  _metadata:
    description: Global
    hidden: true
    type: String
  config:
    _metadata:
      description: config
      hidden: true
      type: String
    password:
      _metadata:
        description: password
        hidden: true
        type: String
    user:
      _metadata:
        description: user
        hidden: true
        type: String
  config2:
    _metadata:
      description: config2
      hidden: true
      type: String
    password:
      _metadata:
        description: password
        hidden: true
        type: String
    user2:
      _metadata:
        description: user2
        hidden: true
        type: String
App1:
  _metadata:
    description: App1
    hidden: true
    type: String
  name:
    _metadata:
      description: name
      hidden: true
      type: String
  value:
    _metadata:
      description: value
      hidden: true
      type: String
App2:
  _metadata:
    description: App2
    hidden: true
    type: String
  name:
    _metadata:
      description: name
      hidden: true
      type: String
```

Any comments remain on the lines of the key where they occur in the input.

Comment: Thanks Anthon. I will try this out. I am new to python and that's where I got stuck. Thanks for solving this by simple dfs.